# Screen Freezes when setting FragmentAdapter

Tags: android

When i'm going from main activity to my second activity screen is freezing for 2 or 3 seconds. My second activity's oncreate method setting the FragmentAdapter for my layout. As below.

```
mStepperLayout = findViewById(R.id.stepperLayout);
mStepperLayout.setAdapter(new MyStepperAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this));
```

MyStepperAdapter class is like below.There are four fragments switching between on button click.

```
public class MyStepperAdapter extends AbstractFragmentStepAdapter {

    private static final String CURRENT_STEP_POSITION_KEY = "s";

    public MyStepperAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
        super(fm, context);
    }

    @Override
    public Step createStep(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                final FragmentOne step1 = new FragmentOne();
                return step1;
            case 1:
                final FragmentTwo step2 = new FragmentTwo();
                return step2;
            case 2:
                final FragmentThree step3 = new FragmentThree();
                return step3;
            case 3:
                final FragmentFour step4 = new FragmentFour();
                return step4;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public StepViewModel getViewModel(@IntRange(from = 0) int position) {
        //Override this method to set Step title for the Tabs, not necessary for other stepper types
        return new StepViewModel.Builder(context)
                .setTitle("test") //can be a CharSequence instead
                .create();
    }
}
```

The all four fragment layouts are using a compound(custom) view. That compound view is repeating 9 to 10 times in single fragment. So there are nearly 40 times it uses in all fragments. This is the Compound View Layout.

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">

    <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
        android:id="@+id/chipselection"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        app:singleSelection="true">

        <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Safe"
            android:checkable="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            app:chipBackgroundColor="@color/bg_chip_safe"/>

        <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checkable="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            app:chipBackgroundColor="@color/bg_chip_atrisk"
            android:text="At Risk" />
    </com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:id="@+id/btnnote"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="12dp"
            android:layout_height="12dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/note"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Note"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
        android:id="@+id/btnphoto"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="12dp"
            android:layout_height="12dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/photo"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Photo"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/notelayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:text="Notes"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editnote"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                android:id="@+id/viewnote"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:drawablePadding="8dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:drawableRight="@mipmap/edit"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                android:id="@+id/actions"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp">

                <Button
                    android:enabled="false"
                    android:id="@+id/btnsave"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Save" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btncancel"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Cancel" />
                <ImageView
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                    android:visibility="invisible"
                    android:id="@+id/btndel"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:padding="12dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@mipmap/delete"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:id="@+id/photol"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:text="Photos"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                android:id="@+id/imgpic"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</merge>
```

So i want to know that is there anyway to achieve this kind of views without freezing the screen? I had tried with the AsyncTask but it doesn't worked for me. Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

the app is freezing because the layouts are heavy on the device, and you can't use AsyncTask for UI stuff, creating layouts only happen on the UI thread, and since your have repeating layouts you can use a RecyclerView to show them instead of writing all of them in xml and showing them all at once.

Comment: but i think by using a recyclerview the user interface will not so friendly. Can i do it like this, create a seperate layout with all the repeating components and add that layout dynamically to the parent layout and show a progress dialog while adding thag layout?

Comment: I don't know if that would solve your problem, even if you did it that way you still may see lag and frame dropping in your app.